# #pragma once ou #ifndef?

Tags: c, c++

Sei que há duas formas de impedir que um arquivo de cabeçalho seja duplicado em C\C++:

```
#ifndef FOO_H_INCLUDED
#define FOO_H_INCLUDED

class Foo
{  
   // código
};

#endif
```

E

```
#pragma once

class Foo
{  
   // código
};
```

Sendo que a primeira eu vejo em quase 100% das bibliotecas *open source* por aí. Então, a  minha dúvida é: se a segunda forma é mais simples e suportada pelos principais compiladores (gcc, msvc, intel, clang), o que há de errado em utilizar `#pragma once`? E que diferença essas abordagens fazem para o compilador?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A grande diferença é que os header guards (`#ifndef`) usam uma funcionalidade do standard e são suportados por todo e qualquer compilador conformante. Já um `#pragma` tem comportamento dependente de cada compilador. É a forma standard de fazer algo não standard. Mas atualmente todos suportam o `#pragma once` e você não precisa realmente se preocupar com encontrar um que não tenha esse suporte.

Sobre qual usar, o interessante é que o `#pragma once` **é mais eficiente**. Os compiladores geralmente checam a primeira linha do arquivo antes de tudo e verificam se é um `#pragma once` e se aquele arquivo já foi carregado. Isso significa que não é necessário fazer um parse completo como ocorreria com o `#ifndef`.

Como ponto negativo, o `#pragma once` vai comparar pelo caminho absoluto do arquivo. Ou seja, se você tiver duas copias exatas do mesmo arquivo e incluir as duas, o `#pragma once` vai falhar em te proteger. Mas realmente... se você tem dois arquivos iguais no seu projeto, tem algo errado.

Nota: Alguns compiladores também encontram formas de otimizar o `#ifndef`, então o ganho de performance pode ser desprezível.

Answer (score 7):

Porque `#pragma once` não faz parte do padrão C/C++ e só é adotado por alguns compiladores, como o Microsoft Visual Studio. Para universalizar seu código para vários compiladores, a melhor abordagem é usar o método clássico com `#ifndef`.

Comment: Mas, se os compiladores alvo suportam, que diferença isso faz? É inseguro?

Comment: @IanMedeiros, segundo a wikipedia o GCC suporta  `pragma once` desde a versão 3.4: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once