# Qual é a diferença entre usar #include "stack.h" ou usar a declaracao dessa class ?

Tags: c++, classes

Tendo estas duas classes, em dois ficheiros `.h` distintos.

*um.h*

```
class um {
  //(...)
};
```

*dois.h*

```
#include "um.h" //opcao 1

class um; //opcao 2

class dois{
  public:
    void f1(um * p);
};
```

Qual a diferença entre estas duas opções e qual a mais indicada?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não são opções, já que não fazem a mesma coisa.

Ao fazer `#include "um.h"` você *de fato* inclui o arquivo de cabeçalho da classe (supostamente já definida), de forma que a partir de então (no local onde está incluindo e recursivamente, se este local também for um cabeçalho) você tem acesso à todos os elementos da interface dela. Isto é, você pode referenciar um atributo ou método dessa classe - claro, dependendo do escopo declarado e de onde a referência está sendo realizada.

Ao fazer `class um;` você apenas declara a classe (isto mesmo, vazia por não ter definição), cuja interface deverá ser fornecida (definida) em algum momento. Isso é comumente chamado de "*forward declaration*", e é útil quando você precisa apenas informar que vai usar essa classe, mas não precisa dos detalhes de sua implementação ainda. Em outras palavras, você diz que vai usar, mas não deseja (ou não pode) incluir o cabeçalho por algum motivo.

Um exemplo de uso é quando uma classe A referencia uma B que referencia A de volta. A classe A inclui o cabeçalho da B, mas a classe B pode apenas indicar que "reconhece" a classe A e assim evita uma referência circular nos *includes*:

**Arquivo b.h:**

```
class A;
class B
{
    A *a;
};
```

**Arquivo a.h:**

```
#include "b.h"
class A
{
    B *b;
};
```

Mas note que eventualmente o compilador precisa encontrar a definição de uma classe predefinida (assim como a sua implementação - o código dos métodos), caso contrário vai produzir erros de compilação e/ou linkedição.

Comment: Fiquei esclarecido. 
Caso se use a declaração deve-se usar o `include` dessa class definida, para evitar eventuais erros?
No entando, no meu problema usando apenas o `include` para uma função tipo `void f1(nomeclass * p);`, recebo erro compilação, que o nomeclass não é identificado, e quando coloco `class nomeclass;`, compilador já identifica, daí a minha questão. E ainda mais, tendo outras classes, o mesmo género de função funcionam apenas com includes. A ordem dos includes tem relevância?

Comment: (1) Sim, naturalmente. (2) Precisa ver qual é o erro, pois se está tudo ok no arquivo .h isso não devia ocorrer. (3) A ordem pode ter relevância dependendo da forma como você desenvolveu. E não apenas isso, mas o tempo de compilação e as dependências também decorrem dessa estrutura. O ideal é separar os arquivos de forma que as classes fiquem o mais independentes possível. E lembre-se de que vc *não precisa* ter um .h para cada classe, pode também declarar e definir mais de uma classe em um mesmo arquivo .h (se isso fizer sentido no seu domínio de problema).

Comment: É um projecto grande, daí cada classe ter o seu .h. Penso que o problema está em, algo ambíguo, pois o que acontece no meu problema, é que tenho duas classes, e ambas as classes necessitam do include uma da outra, ou seja, uma class tem um include .h, e nesse include tem, outro include que se chama a ela própria. E penso que seja daí o problema, daí ter que usar a declaração da classe.

Comment: Bom, nesse caso é só garantir que não ocorra inclusão circular. Leia sobre o [`#pragma once`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/155570/73) e sobre a alternativa com [`#ifndef`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9592/73). Vc também pode usar o [*forward declaration*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124405/73). Na prática é como você preferir, mas eu acho mais claro usar uma das duas alternativas anteriores se for apenas para evitar referência circular.