# Duvida FILE em .h

Tags: c

Bom amigos, sou novo na plataforma, então não sei se estou no lugar certo. Mas gostaria de uma ajuda.
  O meu problema é fazer um programa que copie um arquivo txt para outro arquivo de texto, com a função feita separadamente (em biblioteca). Eu não estou conseguindo entender.
  Vou colocar aqui os arquivos que já fiz, main.c e minha biblioteca (.c e .h).

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "biblio2.h"

    //main.c//

    int main(void) {

    void copiartxt(FILE *file1, FILE *file2);

    FILE *file1 = fopen("Arquivo 1.txt", "r");
    if(file1==NULL){
        printf("ERRO!");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file2 = fopen("Arquivo 2.txt", "w");

    copiartxt(file1, file2);

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);

    return 0;
}


    //biblioteca.h//
    void copiartxt(FILE, FILE);


    //biblioteca.c//
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void copiartxt(FILE *file1, FILE *file2){

    char leitor[1000];

    while(fgets(leitor, 1000, file1)!=NULL){
    fputs(leitor, file2);
        }
    return 0;
    }
```

Alguém poderia me dizer o que está errado?? Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Como está compilando? Qual a mensagem de erro apresentada? Já posso apontar meia dúzia de "erros" ou "fuga de padrões", mas não sei se realmente é o ponto que está te impedindo de fato

Comment: Está dando conflito no copiartxt em main.c

Comment: qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: In function 'main':
[Error] conflicting types for 'copiartxt'

Comment: Em qual arquivo? E como você está fazendo para compilar?

Comment: No main.c. Eu retirei aquela linha do programa principal e apareceu outros erros, na biblioteca.h. E é justamente nessa biblioteca.h que tenho dúvida, pois nunca fiz um programa para mexer em arquivos desse tipo

Comment: Opa, consegui consertar. Deveria ter colocado "struct FILE *" no biblioteca.h. Funcionou como o esperado.

Comment: Pela sua descrição, continua usando do jeito errado. Quando tiver um tempo eu respondo o correto

Comment: Ok amigo. Aguardo a sua versão!!

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/307279/64969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, precisamos conhecer o ciclo de compilação de um arquivo fonte C. Basicamente, ele passa pelos seguintes estágios:

1. pré processador
2. compilação para objeto
3. [linkedição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/64969)

O processo de linkedição se dá quando se está construindo o executável final. Arquivos de compilação intermediários param no passo 2 *compilação para objeto*. Dei mais detalhes [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213804/64969).

Pegando algum contexto da resposta linkada:

> Funções que tiveram *forward declaration* [são referências abertas].
>
> Você pode e deve criar arquivos objetos com referências abertas. Porém você só pode criar executável depois de fechar todas as referências estáticas, depois de fazer todas as ligações, todos os *binds*. E quem faz isso? O linkador.

O que é a tal da *forward declaration*? É uma técnica em que eu ensino ao compilador que algo existirá mais adianto; eu declaro que algo irá existir. Mas, não defino muito sobre ele =) [Leia mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210063/64969) (o exemplo é em C++ mas a ideia é a mesma, declarar algo adiante).

Mas, por que é importante conhecer esse tal de *forward declaration*? Porque...

> Por incrível que pareça, o compilador C trabalha apenas uma única entrada de cada vez. Ele pega essa entrada do chamado pré processador C.

[Fonte](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213804/64969)

## O caso de estudo: `copiartxt`

Você quer criar uma função que receba dois ponteiros de arquivo, que não tenha retorno, e que se chama `copiartxt`. Para poder usar ela em diversos cantos, você tem que ela será compilada parcialmente e poderá usar esse resultado na [linkedição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/64969) e gerar o executável final.

Para tal processo, há o arquivo `biblioteca.c`, que será transformado em `biblioteca.o` (ou `biblioteca.obj`, no mundo Visual Studio se não me engano). Vamos construí-la aos poucos?

Para começar, vamos no seu foco? Ela terá a função `copiartxt` desejada. Então, vamos começar com isso:

```
void copiartxt(FILE *file1, FILE *file2)
{
  char leitor[1000];

  while (fgets(leitor, 1000, file1) != NULL) {
    fputs(leitor, file2);
  }
}
```

> Pode reparar que os nossos códigos são ligeiramente distintos. Eu usei meu *estilo de código*, de posicionamento de chaves e espaçamentos, mas também removi o `return 0;`, já que a função não deveria ter retorno, ela é `void`

Se você por isso para compilar, alguns compiladores vão reclamar que não conhecem `fgets`, nem `fputs`, nem `NULL`, creio que também de `FILE`. Essas funções e essa constante são declaradas no arquivo `<stdio.h>`. Sobre `fgets`, em algum momento de `<stdio,h>` você encontrará uma linha semelhante a esta ([fonte](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)):

```
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream);
```

Sem mais nem menos. Apenas a linha de declaração dessa função. Então, precisamos inserir esse *header* no nosso `biblioteca.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copiartxt(FILE *file1, FILE *file2)
{
  char leitor[1000];

  while (fgets(leitor, 1000, file1) != NULL) {
    fputs(leitor, file2);
  }
}
```

Muito bem, agora deve compilar feliz e sem erros. Após compilar até nível de código objeto (`gcc -c biblioteca.c`, por exemplo), podemos usá-lo em nosso executável.

Agora, vamos para o executável? `main.c` o nome? Pois bem, aqui vamos nós. A razão central desse arquivo é um ponto de entrada de aplicação (a função `main`) que copiará o arquivo `"Arquivo 1.txt"` para o destino `"Arquivo 2.txt"`. Deve dar algum tratamento para os erros também, então vamos lá, codificar a função `main`:

```
int main(void)
{
  FILE *file1 = fopen("Arquivo 1.txt", "r");
  if (file1 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRO ao abrir \"Arquivo 1.txt\"!");
    return 1;
  }

  FILE *file2 = fopen("Arquivo 2.txt", "w");
  if (file2 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRO ao abrir \"Arquivo 2.txt\"!");
    return 1;
  }
  copiartxt(file1, file2);

  fclose(file1);
  fclose(file2);

  return 0;
}
```

> Mudanças que eu fiz:
>
> 1. removi a *forward declaration* que estava dentro da função `main`, depois tratemos isso
> 2. adicionei uma detecção de erros para o `"Arquivo 2.txt"` no mesmo estilo que você fez para `"Arquivo 1.txt"` (vai que estamos em um sistema de arquivos de somente leitura?)
> 3. coloquei uma mensagem de erro um pouco mais específica; agora dá para discernir quem foi a causa do erro
> 4. estou imprimindo na saída de erro `stderr`, pois é lá onde os erros devem ser impressos; para tal, foi necessário usar o `fprintf`

Se tentar compilar sem mais mudanças, o `main.c` apresentará alguns erros. Como por exemplo:

- o que é `NULL`?
- o que é `stderr`?
- cadê a função `fprintf`?
- cadê a função `fopen`?
- cadê a função `fclose`?
- cadê a função `copiartxt`?

Talvez reclame do que seja `FILE`, não lembro. Como corrigir isso? Bem, boa parte se resolve ao incluir o `<stdio.h>`. Então, ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE *file1 = fopen("Arquivo 1.txt", "r");
  if (file1 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRO ao abrir \"Arquivo 1.txt\"!");
    return 1;
  }

  FILE *file2 = fopen("Arquivo 2.txt", "w");
  if (file2 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRO ao abrir \"Arquivo 2.txt\"!");
    return 1;
  }
  copiartxt(file1, file2);

  fclose(file1);
  fclose(file2);

  return 0;
}
```

Mas continua sem a declaração de quem é `copiartxt`. Podemos usar uma *forward declaration* e o compilador ficará feliz.

> **ATENÇÂO**: não é o código final

```
#include <stdio.h>

void copiartxt(FILE *fonte, FILE *destino);

int main(void)
{
  FILE *file1 = fopen("Arquivo 1.txt", "r");
  if (file1 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRO ao abrir \"Arquivo 1.txt\"!");
    return 1;
  }

  FILE *file2 = fopen("Arquivo 2.txt", "w");
  if (file2 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRO ao abrir \"Arquivo 2.txt\"!");
    return 1;
  }
  copiartxt(file1, file2);

  fclose(file1);
  fclose(file2);

  return 0;
}
```

Pronto, agora o compilador está satisfeito. Mas, será que isso é certo?

Veja bem: você precisou declarar no `main.c` uma coisa que é externa a ele. Se existisse algo que desse esse efeito, de ensinar ao compilador que existem *forward declaration* de funções sem precisar estar no arquivo `main.c`...

Mas, espera um pouco! Isso existe! É o que a diretiva de pré-compilação `#include` faz, ela "escreve" no arquivo fonte. Então, se magicamente existir um `biblioteca.h` que declare essa função, estou feito. O código do `main.c` ficaria então:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "biblioteca.h"

int main(void)
{
  FILE *file1 = fopen("Arquivo 1.txt", "r");
  if (file1 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRO ao abrir \"Arquivo 1.txt\"!");
    return 1;
  }

  FILE *file2 = fopen("Arquivo 2.txt", "w");
  if (file2 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRO ao abrir \"Arquivo 2.txt\"!");
    return 1;
  }
  copiartxt(file1, file2);

  fclose(file1);
  fclose(file2);

  return 0;
}
```

Pronto, agora todos estão felizes. Só precisamos criar o `biblioteca.h`, certo? Na verdade, mais ou menos... se você quiser que o arquivo *header* esteja coerente, quem implementa as funções que ele declarou deve, também, incluir o mesmo *header*. Se eu não fizer essa inclusão, poderia definir uma função `copiartxt` com outra assinatura, outras entradas. Então, isso significa que também é necessário fazer alguma alteração no `biblioteca.c`. No caso, a alteração é simplesmente incluir o `biblioteca.h` e ser feliz:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "biblioteca.h"

void copiartxt(FILE *file1, FILE *file2)
{
  char leitor[1000];

  while (fgets(leitor, 1000, file1) != NULL) {
    fputs(leitor, file2);
  }
}
```

Ok, agora só falta criar o arquivo `biblioteca.h`. Como sempre, vamos começar no seu cerne: a *forward declaration* da função `copiartxt`:

```
void copiartxt(FILE *file1, FILE *file2);
```

Pois bem, agora o compilador pode reclamar que não conhece o tipo `FILE`. Então, nada mais justo que já ensinar no *header* quem ele é:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void copiartxt(FILE *file1, FILE *file2);
```

Agora pronto? Bem, ainda não... arquivos *header* em C necessitam de cuidados especiais. Você ***normalmente*** não deseja que ele seja incluído mais de uma vez no código. E sim, isso pode acontecer. Por exemplo, no `biblioteca.c`, há duas diretrizes de inclusão de `<stdio.h>`; a primeira, no próprio arquivo `biblioteca.c`, e a segunda vez no `#include` do `biblioteca.h`. Isso faz parte do pré processamento da linguagem C. Uma das alternativas para se fazer isso é através dos [guardiões de inclusão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9592/64969) (*include guardians*). Um guardião de inclusão clássico usa de duas características do pré processador:

1. posso mandar um texto ao compilador de maneira condicional; portanto, posso ignorar texto de maneira condicional
2. posso declarar coisas

Puxando o exemplo [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9592/64969):

```
#ifndef FOO_H_INCLUDED
#define FOO_H_INCLUDED

class Foo
{  
   // código
};

#endif
```

Ele está protegendo o código através da declaração de `FOO_H_INCLUDED`. Então, podemos usar isso no nosso `biblioteca.h`:

```
#ifndef BIBLIOTECA_H_INCLUDED
#define BIBLIOTECA_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdio.h>
void copiartxt(FILE *file1, FILE *file2);

#endif
```

> Note que o guardião de inclusão deve ser único para cada *header*, caso contrário você pode ativar o guardião de outro *header* e causar uma confusão

Também existe um tal de `#pragma once` que faz algo parecido com o guardião de inclusão, mas é mais eficiente. O problema é que ele não é padrão, então nem todos os compiladores aceitarão ele. [Leia mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9635/64969).

### Mas por que funcionou com `void copiartxt(struct FILE *origem, struct FILE *destino)`?

Basicamente porque, com ponteiros, diversos compiladores C vão ignorar se existe a tal da estrutura declarada. Tratando só como ponteiros, muitos compiladores C conseguem fazer misturas absurdas e nojentas, mas que no final das contas funcionam. Por isso que você pode usar um ponteiro para uma estrutura que não foi declarada (porém que se chama `struct FILE`).

No caso da `<stdio.h>`, em nenhum momento ela disponibiliza para você um `struct FILE`, pois você não precisa saber como é um `FILE` internamente. Por exemplo, na [`<stdio.h>` disponibilizado pela GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/m68hc11/examples/stdio_8h-source.html), linha 51:

```
typedef struct __sFILE FILE;
```

## Notas adicionais

Se desejar ter compatibilidade com C++, basta incluir todos os *forward declaration* dentro de um bloco `extern "C"`. Mas só faça isso para C++, C não conhece blocos `extern "C"`:

```
#ifndef BIBLIOTECA_H_INCLUDED
#define BIBLIOTECA_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void copiartxt(FILE *file1, FILE *file2);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

## Resumindo

Arquivo `biblioteca.h` (compatibilizado com C++):

```
#ifndef BIBLIOTECA_H_INCLUDED
#define BIBLIOTECA_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void copiartxt(FILE *file1, FILE *file2);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Arquivo `biblioteca.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "biblioteca.h"

void copiartxt(FILE *file1, FILE *file2)
{
  char leitor[1000];

  while (fgets(leitor, 1000, file1) != NULL) {
    fputs(leitor, file2);
  }
}
```

Arquivo `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "biblioteca.h"

int main(void)
{
  FILE *file1 = fopen("Arquivo 1.txt", "r");
  if (file1 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRO ao abrir \"Arquivo 1.txt\"!");
    return 1;
  }

  FILE *file2 = fopen("Arquivo 2.txt", "w");
  if (file2 == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERRO ao abrir \"Arquivo 2.txt\"!");
    return 1;
  }
  copiartxt(file1, file2);

  fclose(file1);
  fclose(file2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sua explicação foi fantástica. Consegui compreender muita coisa. Muito obrigado!!

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar a questão que melhor lhe atendeu como aceita (você pode mudar a aceitação depois). O melhor reconhecimento que você pode dar aqui no StackOverflow em português é com a positivação e a aceitação de respostas. Em breve você terá reputação o suficiente para poder votar positivamente

Comment: Posso melhorar minha resposta? Ela tem algum ponto em que errei e não percebi?

Comment: Sua resposta já supriu minhas dúvidas. Não posso te responder se tem algum erro ou não pois sou iniciante em C, qualquer errinho passa despercebido por mim.

Comment: @GustavoPavanati minha última mensagem fora destinada àquele que me negativou. Se votou negativo é porque minha resposta pode ser melhorada, confere?

Answer (score 0):

Para copiar o conteúdo de um ficheiro para o outro ficheiro pode fazer como fez, o uso de um ficheiro .h é poder usar funções de um ficheiro .c noutro ficheiro ou até mesmo no próprio .h sem ter de ter lá o código, apenas o cabeçalho da função.

Por exemplo no seu caso pode ter um ficheiro, por exemplo teste.c que contem o código da função `copiar_ficheiro()` e o seu respectivo ficheiro .h que contem o cabeçalho da função e por exemplo uma main() que executa o código.

**teste.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "teste.h"


void copiar_ficheiro(FILE *file1, FILE *file2){
    char leitor[1000];
    while(fgets(leitor, 1000, file1)){
        fprintf(file2,"%s", leitor);
    }

}
```

**teste.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void copiar_ficheiro(FILE *file1, FILE *file2);

int main()
{
    FILE *file1, *file2;

    file1 = fopen("Arquivo 1.txt", "r");
    if (file1 == NULL) {
        printf("Erro\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    file2 = fopen("Arquivo 2.txt", "w");
    if (file2 == NULL) {
        printf("Erro\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    copiar_ficheiro(file1, file2);

    fclose(file1);
    fclose(file2);
    return 0;
}
```

Espero ter esclarecido sua dúvida.

Comment: Não ficou claro aqui como é o arquivo `teste.h`. Parece que nele você pôs código, como a função `main`

Comment: Vou testar aqui. No mais, muito obrigado!!

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado O ficheiro .h tanto ser para definir o cabeçalho de funções, como sendo um interface, e foi isso que eu expliquei. Pode ainda ter uma função main que executa essas funções ou não, depende do uso que cada pessoa lhe queira dar.

Comment: Lendo apenas a sua resposta, não entendi que o `.h` seria só a interface. No texto corrido, logo após **`test.h`**, você colocou duas diretrizes de pré compilação fazendo inclusão, uma _forward declaration_ da função desejado e, então, a função `main`. É isso que está na estrutura de sua resposta, e isso que eu não entendi: por que colocou implementação em um arquivo de cabeçalho?, ainda mais implementação da `main`?