# Dividir o programa com bibliotecas .c e .h

Tags: c

Amigos, acabei de fazer um programa para calcular a matriz transposta. Minha dúvida é: como posso transformar esse programa em função, de tal modo que eu tenha mais dois arquivos (um .c e um .h) além do main.c?! Espero que tenham entendido minha questão. Segue abaixo meu código em C:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int matriz_1[2][2];
int matriz_2[2][2];
int i, j;

matriz_1[0][0] = 1;
matriz_1[0][1] = 2;
matriz_1[1][0] = 3;
matriz_1[1][1] = 4;

for(i = 0;i < 2;i++) {
    for(j = 0;j < 2;j++) {
        matriz_2[j][i] = matriz_1[i][j];
    }
}

for(i = 0;i < 2;i++) {
    printf("[ ");
    for(j = 0;j < 2;j++) {
        printf("%d ", matriz_2[i][j]);
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Obrigado!!

Comment: Qual sistema operacional esta usando? Qual o compilador esta usando?

Comment: Estou usando de so Windows 10 e o Dev C++ como compilador

Comment: você tem que escrever a implementação da função (o corpo da função) no arquivo .c, a definição no arquivo .h. http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/329/lectures/node22.html

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/306786/64969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para dividir em `.c` e `.h` bastaria criar uma função no `.h`, e no `.c` colocar todo o código que tem. Depois apenas seria necessário chamar no `main`. Isso não seria grande ideia mas ficaria assim:

matriz.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef MATRIZ_H_INCLUDED
#define MATRIZ_H_INCLUDED

void programa_matriz();

#endif // MATRIZ_H_INCLUDED
```

matriz.c

```
#include "matriz.h"
void programa_matriz(){
    //todo o código que tinha no main aqui
}
```

main.c

```
#include "matriz.c"
int main(){
    programa_matriz();
    return 0;
}
```

### Dividir funções por funcionalidades

Uma das ideias de separar em `.h` e `.c` é poder incluir os `.h` e utilizar as funções que precisa para cada funcionalidade em separado. Significa isto que dificilmente fará sentido "transformar um programa em função" mas sim transformar cada funcionalidade numa função dando assim o máximo de reutilização e organização possível do código.

No seu caso podia pelo menos separar em duas funções:

- inverter matriz
- mostrar matriz

Deixando a criação das matrizes no `main` mesmo.

Exemplo:

matriz.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef MATRIZ_H_INCLUDED
#define MATRIZ_H_INCLUDED

void inverter_matriz(int matriz[2][2], int matriz_invertida[2][2]);
void mostrar_matriz(int matriz[2][2]);

#endif // MATRIZ_H_INCLUDED
```

matriz.c

```
#include "matriz.h"

void inverter_matriz(int matriz[2][2], int matriz_invertida[2][2]){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            matriz_invertida[j][i] = matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void mostrar_matriz(int matriz[2][2]){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("[ ");
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("]\n");
    }
}
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "matriz.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int matriz_1[2][2];
    int matriz_2[2][2];

    matriz_1[0][0] = 1;
    matriz_1[0][1] = 2;
    matriz_1[1][0] = 3;
    matriz_1[1][1] = 4;

    inverter_matriz(matriz_1, matriz_2);
    mostrar_matriz(matriz_2);

    return 0;
}
```