# Como modularizar o seguinte código C

Tags: c, funções, modularização

Abaixo segue um código para entrada de data pelo usuário e validação do mesmo, porém gostaria de modularizar ela. Não sei se existe a possibilidade de usar ela fora do mais, ou em um arquivo externo (ex: "validacao.h"). Consigo deixar ele mais enxuto? Desde já obrigado.

Edit1: No caso, terei que rodar este programa em um "corretor.c" que é baseado em função, e existem mais tarefas para serem implementadas no código, então por isso gostaria que ele ficasse o mais enxuto possível, e a primeira coisa que veio em minha mente foi exatamente fazer os possíveis cálculos e validações em um arquivo externo "lálálá.h" e deixar somente a interação no arquivo principal "main.c".

Edit2: Exatamente o que o usuário Lacobus mencionou, era o que eu necessitava compreender para prosseguir com o desenvolvimento das questões. Obrigado!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct DMA{
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
};
typedef struct DMA dma;


int main(void)
{
    dma data;

    printf("Informe a data: ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &data.dia, &data.mes, &data.ano);

    if(data.ano >= 10 && data.ano <= 9999){ //!checa o ano

        if (data.mes >= 1 && data.mes <= 12){ //! checa o mes

            if ((data.dia >= 1 && data.dia <= 31) && (data.mes == 1 || data.mes == 3 || data.mes == 5 || data.mes == 7 || data.mes == 8  || data.mes == 10 || data.mes == 12)){
                puts("Data valida!"); //!checa os meses que tem 31 dias
            }
            else 
            if ((data.dia >= 1 && data.dia <= 30) && (data.mes == 4 || data.mes == 6 || data.mes == 9 || data.mes == 11)){
                puts("Data valida!"); //!checa os meses que tem 30 dias
            }
            else if (data.dia >=1 && data.dia <= 28 && data.mes == 2){
                puts("Data valida!"); //!valida as datas do mes 2
            }

            else if (data.dia == 29 && data.mes == 2 && (data.ano % 400 == 0 || (data.ano % 4 ==0 && data.ano % 100 != 0))){
                puts("Data valida! (Ano bissexto)"); //!checa o ano bissexto e imprime informando
            }

            else{
                puts("## ATENCAO: Dia invalido! ##"); //!informa caso DIA inserido for invalido
            }
        }
        else{
            puts("## ATENCAO: Mes invalido! ##"); //!informa caso MES inserido for invalido
        }
    }

    else{
        puts("## ATENCAO: Ano invalido! ##"); //!informa caso ANO inserido for invalido
    }


    return 0;
}
```

PS: As "!" nos comentários é que uso VSCode e uma extensão que deixa os comentários coloridos com caracteres especiais.

Comment: A sua questão é como separar o código em `.h` e `.c` ? Se for o caso há bem pouco tempo respondi a uma questão igual: [dividir-o-programa-com-bibliotecas-c-e-h](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/307279/dividir-o-programa-com-bibliotecas-c-e-h/307346#307346)

Comment: Dei uma olhada por cima, e parece-me ser o que preciso. Vou olhar com calma agora e tentar executar o código. Obrigado @Isac !

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dividir o programa com bibliotecas .c e .h](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/307279/dividir-o-programa-com-bibliotecas-c-e-h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um código enxuto e modularizado capaz de resolver o seu problema:

**foobar.h**:

```
#ifndef __FOOBAR_H__
#define __FOOBAR_H__

#define ERR_DIA_BISSEXTO_INVALIDO  (-4)
#define ERR_DIA_INVALIDO           (-3)
#define ERR_MES_INVALIDO           (-2)
#define ERR_ANO_INVALIDO           (-1)
#define DATA_OK                    (0)

#define BISSEXTO(ano) ((ano % 4) == 0 && ((ano % 100) != 0 || (ano % 400) == 0))

int validar_data( int dia, int mes, int ano );

#endif
```

**foobar.c**:

```
#include "foobar.h"

int validar_data( int dia, int mes, int ano )
{
    if( ano < 10 || ano > 9999 )
        return ERR_ANO_INVALIDO;
    else if( mes < 1 || mes > 12 )
        return ERR_MES_INVALIDO;
    else if( (dia > 31) && (mes == 1 || mes == 3 || mes == 5 || mes == 7 || mes == 8  || mes == 10 || mes == 12) )
        return ERR_DIA_INVALIDO;
    else if( (dia > 30) && (mes == 4 || mes == 6 || mes == 9 || mes == 11) )
        return ERR_DIA_INVALIDO;
    else if( !BISSEXTO( ano ) && mes == 2 && dia > 28 )
        return ERR_DIA_BISSEXTO_INVALIDO;
    else if( BISSEXTO( ano ) && mes == 2 && dia > 29 )
        return ERR_DIA_BISSEXTO_INVALIDO;
    else
        return DATA_OK;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "foobar.h"

int main( void )
{
    int ret, dia, mes, ano;

    printf("Informe a data (DD/MM/AAAA): ");

    ret = scanf("%d/%d/%d", &dia, &mes, &ano );

    if( ret != 3 )
    {
        printf( "Data nao formatada corretamente!\n" );
        return 0;
    }

    ret = validar_data( dia, mes, ano );

    switch( ret )
    {
        case DATA_OK:
            printf( "Data valida!\n" );
            break;
        case ERR_ANO_INVALIDO:
            printf( "Ano invalido!\n" );
            break;
        case ERR_MES_INVALIDO:
            printf( "Mes invalido!\n" );
            break;
        case ERR_DIA_INVALIDO:
            printf( "Dia invalido!\n" );
            break;
        case ERR_DIA_BISSEXTO_INVALIDO:
            printf( "Dia invalido para um ano bissexto!\n" );
            break;
        default:
            printf( "Data invalida!\n" );
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```